# What kind of reduction is in: "...digging out ancient objects, archaeologists must interpret..."?

Tags: relative-clauses, conjunction-reduction

> When finished with digging out ancient objects, archaeologists must interpret what they have found.

What kind of reduction is in my example?

Comment: There's no reduction. The non-finite clause "finished with digging out ancient objects" has no overt subject, like most non-finite clauses, but that's normal and not a case of reduction.

Comment: Thank you for help ,Bill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a case of elision, the implied full sentence being:

> When [they are] finished with digging out ancient objects, archaeologists must interpret what they have found.

the implied subject thus being "archaeologists", via an implied pronoun. I would not call this reduction, because the implied words were not part of a relative clause.